# Virtual Functions and Polymorphism - unable to declare object in test class

Tags: c++

I've created a program that uses virtual functions and polymorphism to calculate the parameter and area for three different objects: circles, rectangles and right angled triangles. Whenever I try to assign one of the different object classes to the pointer I have in my test class, it says 'Error: expected a type specifier':

```
shape_ptr = new Rectangle;
```

Screenshot [of error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7M0p.png)

I'm almost sure it's something really simple that I've missed but it's not the inclusion of the header file as I've done that on each class without any mistakes that I can see. Here is my code:

Base Class:

```
#ifndef SHAPE
#define SHAPE
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void compute_area() = 0; // a pure virtual function
    virtual void compute_perimeter() = 0; // a pure virtual function
    virtual void read_shape_data() = 0; // a pure virtual function
    virtual void print_result() { // a virtual function
        cout << "The area is " << area << endl;
        cout << "The perimeter is " << perim << endl;
    }
protected: // protected access specifier
    double area, perim;
};


#endif
```

circle.cpp:

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    void compute_area() { area = pi * radius; }
    void compute_perimeter() { perim = 2 * pi * radius; }
    void read_shape_data() {
        cout << "Enter radius of the rectangle : ";
        cin >> radius;
    }
private:
    int radius;
    double pi = 3.14159265359;
};
```

rectangle.cpp:

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    void compute_area() { area = width * height; }
    void compute_perimeter() { perim = 2 * width + 2 * height; }
    void read_shape_data() {
        cout << "Enter width of the rectangle : ";
        cin >> width;
        cout << "Enter height of the rectangle : ";
        cin >> height;
    }
private:
    int width, height;
};
```

RightTriangle.cpp:

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class RightTriangle : public Shape
{
public:
    void compute_area() { area = base * height; }
    void compute_perimeter() { perim = pow((pow(base, 2) * pow(height, 2)), 2); }
    void read_shape_data() {
        cout << "Enter base length of triangle : ";
        cin >> base;
        cout << "Enter height of triangle : ";
        cin >> height;
        cout <<  
    }
private:
    int radius, base, height;
};
```

test.cpp (test class):

```
#include "shape.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int choice;
    Shape* shape_ptr = NULL;
    cout << "Enter 1 for circle, 2 for rectangle, 3 for right angled triangle or 0 for exit";
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            shape_ptr = new Rectangle;
            break;
    }

    shape_ptr->read_shape_data();
    shape_ptr->compute_area();
    shape_ptr->compute_perimeter();
    shape_ptr->print_result();
    delete shape_ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time and I'm happy to answer any questions.

Comment: You're missing a `#include "Rectangle.h"`

Comment: Why are your functions all void, and not returning anything either by reference or to the function? If you're planning to use void might as well print the answer in the function?

Comment: It's just the way my lecturer wanted us to do it, it was to learn about virtual functions and polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "shape.h" header doesn't automatically know about the definitions of derived classes like `Rectangle`, so your test file needs to include those headers too:

```
#include "shape.h"
#include "rectangle.h"
// etc.
#include <iostream>
```

It looks like you defined your derived classes within .cpp files. Move those *declarations* into header files, and define them in the .cpp file instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that makes sense. How would I move the declarations to the shape.h? I tried:

class Rectangle : public Shape;

But it didn't like that.

Comment: Create a new header for each Rectangle where you place the declaration for class Rectangle, etc. You will have many .h files, not just one.

Comment: I assume I need to mention the compute_area, compute_perimeter and read_shape_data methods too even though they're mentioned in the shape.h yeah? Just wanted to avoid duplication but if that's the correct way to do it then I'll happily do it that way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about duplication? Do you mean retyping the function names when you implement in the .cpp file? Then yes. It's optional, I suppose, to do this in a .cpp file, but it's good practice. Don't forget include guards in your other .h files like you have for Shape.

Comment: I think I got it. Last question is, do I need to specify the access specifiers in the source file or just the header file?

Comment: This is an example of the circle.h I've just made: http://pastebin.com/raw/kT89rd1e

Does that look like it's following good practice? What I was meaning about duplication is I'm defining the three methods again when they were already defined in shape.h but they're virtual so I think I do need to define them in each .h file, right?

Comment: And here is my circle.cpp after moving stuff to the .h: http://pastebin.com/raw/mCQFw8zc